# How to store sqlite file in Hadoop with nodejs on daily basis

Tags: node.js, sqlite, hadoop

I want to store sqlite file in hadoop with the help of nodejs, and storing will be done on daily basis (like creating a scheduler that will schedule storing of file in hadoop.

I tried first storing data in sqlite and its getting store in sqlite file and now i stuck on how to store sqlite file in hadoop.
Please help me with i am new to this technology.

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop is not designed to store sqlite files. Hive, for example, would prefer you store ORC or Parquet files, though JSON works too, if that's easier from Nodejs.

If you just want a relational database, use Postgres or Mysql, not Hadoop

Otherwise, file extension doesn't matter. HDFS will happily accept the bytes of any file; you just can't query the sqlite file anymore once it's there